# Strange Emacs behavior (produces garbage on the screen)

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to learn Emacs and eLisp by writing some simple macros. Here is one of them:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d")        'local-delete-line)
```

```lisp
(defun local-delete-line ()
  "deletes 1 line"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (set-mark-command)
  (next-line)
  (delete-region))
```

Unfortunately, after triggering `C-c d` (or any other hotkey that I set up by `global-set-key`), Emacs responds with this:

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas what can cause this?

To troubleshoot, I've removed my whole `.emacs` file, created an empty one, and I've put only the definition of `local-delete-line` function, together with `global-set-key` command. Emacs still produces garbage when invoking the function.

Comment: It's probably elisp bytecode.

Comment: You should just see an error message saying that you have supplied the wrong number of arguments to some function.  You supplied none and one was required.  There might be something wrong with your Emacs installation if you are seeing byte-code here and you started Emacs using `emacs -Q` (which you should do, for testing).

Comment: You never have to empty your init file to have Emacs disregard it.  Just start Emacs using `emacs -Q`.  The `-Q` tells Emacs not to load your init file (`~/.emacs`).

Comment: A small nit: you've defined a function, not a macro.  Lisp macros are something else entirely from keyboard macros or macros in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start by reading the doc of `set-mark-command` (`C-h f set-mark-command`).  See what it says about not setting the mark in code you write.  See how many arguments it **requires**.
2. Read the doc of `delete-region`: it **requires two arguments**.
3. Do `M-: (setq debug-on-error t)`, and then try your recipe.  The backtrace buffer will tell you what you have done wrong.
4. State what it is that you are trying to do.  So far, it seems like you just want to delete or kill a line.  If so, what's wrong with `C-k`?

Comment: What does the \*Messages\* buffer say, any errors there?

Comment: Thanks! Nothing really wrong with internal commands, I just want to learn elisp. Also I'm trying to simulate vim's `dd` command, or Eclipse's `Ctrl+D`. I've changed the code to use the `point` function to get proper arguments for `delete-region`, and now it works.

Comment: If you're coming from vim, you should check out `evil-mode`, which is a great vim emulation layer.